# Htaccess Redirect For Partial Match - URL Begins With Same Elements

Tags: string, .htaccess, redirect, wildcard

I'm trying to redirect a bunch of similar URLS to the front page and they all begin with the same string, but I'm not finding samples for this. How might I accomplish this?

Examples:

```
/quote-of-the-day-5/
/quote-of-the-day-4/
/quote-of-the-day-14/
```

And I'd like to redirect to the root `/`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^quote-of-the-day-(.*)$ http://yourwebsite.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hi Brum, Thanks for your suggestion, but it didn't seem to change anything. Any thoughts as to what I might have done wrong? (I did substitute my own website URL ;-) )

I'm going to try to research how to configure rewrite rules because most of my redirects are straight page to page 301s...

Comment: Mmhh, that is weird? I tried it on my own website and it worked, what is your rewrite base? Maybe adding a / before quote-of-the-day-(.*)?